# How to print file directly, circumventing the print dialog?

Tags: printing, chromium

How to print in single command/shortcut (like Ctrl+P) without showing the print configuration  window?

Comment: @hakermania This isn't really a duplicate. The OP asks to print from any program without the standard dialog, *not* to print a PDF directly.

Comment: i have a network project for billing  so it is difficult to select and print printer and printing option, is their any print config file? how to congig and where it is located

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS that's why the 'possible' word exists ;) I thought that via the command the print dialog is not being shown.

Comment: @raghulrnair I suspect there might not be any way to do this *in general*, but that you could do it for particular applications, or at least those that support programmable macros (like LibreOffice). Are there specific programs you most need this for?

Answer (score 1):

There's only one way to do this, and it's a bit of nuisance. If you start Chromium with [this extra option](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=31395),

```
chromium-browser --kiosk-printing
```

you shouldn't get a print dialog when you try to print. If you ever need to access the print dialog, however, you'll have to completely quit Chromium and restart it without that option.